# Leaky newly installed PVC drainage pipe

Tags: plumbing, water, drainage, pvc

I am pretty bad doing handy work. Anyways, I decided to add a water drainage to my concrete flat roof. I had mocked up all the pipes and finally waited for a sunny day to remove it all and glue all the elbows, Ts and connectors with clear PVC cement. Today after I got home from work it had rained recently and noticed that it was leaking. I can't isolate from which connection exactly it is leaking from, yet.

Aside from having to cut everything and doing it over and or hiring somebody, what can you guys recommend? Bear in mind that this is on an area exposed to the elements.

If it rains and there is still daylight left, I'll try to post a video.

Comment: Have you considered using a hose to put water through your drain to try and find the leak without waiting for rain?

Comment: I doubt my hose is long enough to reach the drain hole, but gonna' have to try.

Comment: How about a bucket of water?

Comment: Buckets, making water portable for over 500,000 years.

Comment: I got a hose and poured water down the roof drain and found the leak. I believe it was due to not inserting the tube completely in through the elbow connector. [Here] (http://imgur.com/a/xt8lS) is a picture of it. I know the roof looks bad; one thing at a time... I added a bit of marine silicone sealant to the connector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a long sweep PVC elbow, and you'll save yourself having to make junctions on either side of the flawed regular elbow.  Or, caulk it and hope.

Comment: Cutting out the leaking elbow in such a way that the cut ends fit nicely into a new long sweep elbow is a good idea. May not be necessary. Since the water is not under pressure, there's a fair chance sealant alone will stop the leak.

Comment: I had used marine grade silicone sealant for a couple months and so far it has been working.